# Simplify$\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^{|k-j|}}{k} }{\sqrt{c - \left(\sum_{k'=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^{|k'-j|}}{k'} \right)^2}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Assume $r \in (0,1)$, $i > 0$. I'm looking at the following summation:

$$ \sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^{|k-j|}}{k} }{\sqrt{c^2 - \left(\sum_{k'=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^{|k'-j|}}{k'} \right)^2}} $$
where $c$ is a known constant, such, that $c > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^{|k-j|}}{k}$. This is a part of a larger summation that I'm untangling, that has a correlation-like  structure.

Are there any known tricks on how to simplify a form like this for the exact results?

---

P.S. The form of $c$ is below, however I wasn't certain that it would help with the squared-root:
$$c = \sum_{i,j}^{\infty}\frac{r^{|i-j|}}{ij} + const.$$

Comment: Assuming the inner sum always converges, you can save yourself a bit of typing/writing and assign it a direct symbol like $S_{r,j}$, and this may provide further insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your sum diverges.**

The key term in your expression is $$S_j=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{r^{|j-k|}}{k}}$$  Phrased in terms of $S_j$, you are trying to understand $$A=\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}{\frac{S_j}{\sqrt{\gamma^2-S_j^2}}}$$ where $$\gamma=\text{const}+\sum_k{\frac{S_k}{k}}$$  I will show that $S_j\propto\frac{1}{j}$.  This will then cause the sum defining $A$ to fail to converge.

$S_j$ doesn't have a nice expression.  It contains what I will call "logarithm-type" sums, from the following Taylor series: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{r^{k}}{k}}=-\log{(1-r)}$$  But the terms in $S_j$ aren't the full Taylor series, and, unlike the geometric series, there is no convenient formula for partial sums.  On the other hand, as $j\to\infty$, those "logarithm-type" sums can be well-approximated by geometric series, for which we do understand the partial sums.  So let's estimate $S_j$ in that limit.

First, simplify a little by noting that \begin{align*}
S_j&=\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}{\frac{r^{k-j}}{k}}+\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}{\frac{r^{j-k}}{k}} \\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{\frac{r^p}{j+p}}+\sum_{p=1}^{j-1}{\frac{r^p}{j-p}} \\
&=\frac{1}{j}\left(\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{\frac{r^p}{1+\frac{p}{j}}}+\sum_{p=1}^{j-1}{\frac{r^p}{1-\frac{p}{j}}}\right)
\end{align*}

Now one can Taylor expand in $\frac{p}{j}$, keeping as many terms as one would like.*  I'm only going to expand to zeroth order: \begin{align*}
S_j&=\frac{1}{j}\left(\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{r^p\left(1+O(j^{-1})\right)}+\sum_{p=1}^{j-1}{r^p\left(1+O(j^{-1})\right)}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{j}\left(\frac{1}{1-r}+\frac{r-r^j}{1-r}+O(j^{-1})\right) \\
&=\frac{1+r-r^j}{j(1-r)}+O(j^{-2})
\end{align*}

This will suffice to show that $A=\infty$.  If you wanted something stronger (maybe an estimate for partial sums of $A$ in terms of $r$?), note that you can bound the omitted terms quite concretely: for example, \begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{\frac{r^p}{j+p}}-\frac{1}{j}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{r^p}\right|&\leq\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{|r|^p\left|\frac{1}{j+p}-\frac{1}{j}\right|} \\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{|r|^p\frac{p}{j(j+p)}} \\
&\leq\frac{1}{j^2}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{p|r|^p} \\
&=\frac{1}{j^2(1-|r|)^2}
\end{align*}  This trick works because while logarithm-type sums arise from integrating (finite) geometric series (which have no nice antiderivative), sums of the form $\sum_p{pr^p}$ arise from differentiating…which is always easy to compute.

In any case, to show that $A=\infty$, we can avoid such fiddly computations.  Substituting, $$A=\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}{\frac{\frac{1+r-r^j}{j(1-r)}+O(j^{-2})}{\sqrt{\gamma^2-\left(\frac{1+r-r^j}{j(1-r)}\right)^2+O(j^{-4})}}}$$  This, too, is amenable to Taylor expansion.  By Newton's series, \begin{align*}
A&=\frac{1}{\gamma}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1+r-r^j}{j(1-r)}+O(j^{-2})\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{1+r-r^j}{\gamma j(1-r)}\right)^2+O(j^{-4})\right)^{-1/2}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\gamma}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1+r-r^j}{j(1-r)}+O(j^{-2})\right)\left(1+O(j^{-2})\right)} \\
&=\frac{1}{\gamma}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1+r}{1-r}\frac{1}{j}-\frac{r^j}{j(1-r)}+O(j^{-2})\right)}
\end{align*}

The first term is a scaled harmonic series, which should diverge.  Can it be canceled by the other two?

No, they are convergent series (compare with the geometric and $p$-series, respectively).  So $A$ must diverge.

* This is a bit ambitious, actually, since $p>j$ for all but finitely many terms in the first sum.  So our Taylor series actually fails to converge for those sums.  But those terms are multiplied by an exponential decay, so it ends up not mattering.  For a precise analysis, see the subsequent discussion of estimating the error precisely, or consider the following alternative: let $F_j=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{\frac{r^p}{j+p}}$.  Then $$F_j=\sum_{p=0}^{j-1}{\frac{r^p}{j+p}}+r^j\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}{\frac{r^p}{2j+p}}$$  Noting that the second term is $r^jF_{2j}$, we can iterate; since the remainder terms tend to $0$, we have $$F_j=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{r^{(2^k-1)j}\sum_{p=0}^{2^kj-1}{\frac{r^p}{2^kj+p}}}$$ which does admit a Taylor expansion.  In any case, the end result will be the same: $S_j=\frac{C}{j}+O(j^{-2})$.

Comment: Excellent writeup, thanks a lot for all the additional comments, really helpful!

Comment: As a side note, if we look at the initial sum as a limit of partial sums (up to $p$, $p \to \infty$), would you think my guess is correct that multiplying it by $p^{-1}$ or even $p^{-1/2}$ should help with convergence? Or would it still diverge? Will try to check that.

Comment: @runr: Yes; my argument shows that the partial sums up to $p$ are roughly a scaled harmonic series, which grows like $\log{(p)}$.  So the partial sums divided by $\sqrt{p}$ converge to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, still digesting the answer! :)

Comment: Could you clarify how did you apply the Newton's series to arrive at the second equality, that follows the words ... _By Newton's series_ ...?  Following the same logic, I'm arriving at $\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^{p} \sum_{j=i+1}^{p}\left(c^2 r^{-2i} \right) \left( c^2 - \frac{1}{i^2}
  \frac{\left(r^{-i+p+1}+r^i-r-1\right)^2}{(r-1)^2}  + O(i^{-4}) \right)^{-1} $ for another very similar problem. Would like to also simplify it further, removing the $^{-1}$ power, but not sure that I understand the Newton step fully.

Comment: @runr: I'm applying it to the second factor, and being a little pretentious by even mentioning it.  Newton's series says that $$(1+\alpha x+O(x^2))^{-1/2}=1-\frac{\alpha x}{2}+O(x^2)=1+O(x)$$  In my example, $x=j^{-2}$.